# Line continuation in `cmd` script to run `powershell` command

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to change this one long line into multiple lines in the `cmd` script.

```
powershell.exe -Command "Send-MailMessage -To 'pwatson@company.com' -From 'pwatson@company.com' -Subject 'Standard Extract Request' -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' -Attachment 'file.txt'"
```

Using the `cmd` line continuation character, "^", does not work. Likewise, using the `powershell` line continuation character, "`", also fails.

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
powershell.exe -Command "Send-MailMessage ^
  -To 'pwatson@company.com' ^
  -From 'pwatson@company.com' &
  -Subject 'Standard Extract Request' ^
  -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' ^
  -Attachment 'file.txt'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the " around the Command and change the & by a ^test, like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command Send-MailMessage ^
  -To 'pwatson@company.com' ^
  -From 'pwatson@company.com' ^
  -Subject 'Standard Extract Request' ^
  -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' ^
  -Attachment 'file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. If you want to wrap PowerShell statements, put them in a .ps1 file:

```bsh
Send-MailMessage `
  -To 'pwatson@company.com' `
  -From 'pwatson@company.com' `
  -Subject 'Standard Extract Request' `
  -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' `
  -Attachment 'file.txt'
```

and run that file:

```cmd
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

Comment: Are you saying that this is not possible? There are several parameters that would also need to be passed to the .ps1 script. The actual code is not hardcoded like this example.

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't possible. I just don't recommend^W^Wactively discourage it. Wrapping PowerShell in batch is like hurting yourself on purpose. PowerShell is far more versatile than batch, so don't impose the restrictions of batch files on yourself without a good reason.

Comment: I do realize the capabilities of pipelined objects in PowerShell. I would use it much more if permitted. In this case, there is one (1) PowerShell command in one (1) cmd script for the entire project. Many would prefer never getting out of cmd. I only want to get the work done, but I am not a PowerShell evangelist.